# When I have my webcam open in skype and walk away for any length of time my screensaver does not come on. How can I fix it so screensaver comes on?

Tags: screensaver

Is there any way to make my screensaver come on when my webcam is open in Skype? The screensaver will work when my webcam is not being used.

Comment: Even when you do not have the webcam on, Skype will STILL not go into screensaver mode. You could definitely rephrase the question so that's taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this, because when the webcam is enabled the computer is not in an idle mode since it's receiving input from a peripheral device. Skype doesn't have a way to tell whether you are in front of the webcam or not, it can only detect if the webcam is enabled or disabled.

If you did do this, and say you set the screensaver to come on after 30 minutes, the screen saver would start every 30 minutes if you didn't have some sort of input to the PC (mouse movement, volume adjustment, etc). That would be kind of annoying if you ask me.

You could make a shortcut on your desktop to start the screensaver. Then you would have to manually start the screen saver each time you got up and want it to start using a screen saver. However, I believe the webcam would still continue to run, so the other person could see everything, but from your point of view it would show your screensaver.

The easiest thing to do, would be to turn off the webcam prior to getting up and walking away.

Comment: In particular, if you did this, the screen saver would come on if you didn't use the keyboard and mouse for some amount of time even if you were sitting there talking to somebody on Skype.